# How to record video and audio simultaneously via kinect camera

Tags: matlab, audio, video, kinect

I would like to record sound via Kinect microphones and movement via Kinect depth camera simultaneously. I have a code for recording each one separately but I need to collect data at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually record video and audio on the official kinect SDK 2.0 itself by using their software. If you haven't got them yet you can download it here: [Kinect for Windows SDK 2.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/download/details.aspx?id=44561)

On the software go to RECORD.
and ensure you have Nui Title Audio and Nui System Info turned on as shown below.
[image: Record audio and video on Kinect studio]

Click the red dot(record button) and you are good to go!
be sure you know where the clips are located. you can change them in the settings found here.
Go to FILE > Settings > Recording File Path

[image]